# Redirecting depending on IP Country (Geo-IP)

Tags: javascript, php, geoip

This code shows the page while running and then redirects it.
I want it to redirect very quickly, but it does not.

Where I made the application blogspot.com

```
<script>
  fetch('https://freegeoip.app/json/')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    if(data.country_code == 'TR') {
      window.location.replace("https://www.google.com");
    }
  })
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "very quickly"? What have you tried to check **why** that does not work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

**1. JavaScript solution with browser language (no delay)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var browserLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage; 
if(browserLang.slice(0, 2) == 'tr') {
    window.location.replace("https://www.google.com");
}
</script>
```

If it has to be GeoIP, you have to use a serverside language (like PHP) and do it from there. You could also use geo-ip tables, which are a bit faster.

**2. PHP solution with an external API (`ipapi.com`)**

```
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$access_key = 'YOUR_API_KEY'; // <-- Replace with your api key!

try {
    $ch = curl_init('https://api.ipapi.com/'.$ip.'?access_key='.$access_key);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $json = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $api_result = json_decode($json, true);

    if (
        $api_result !== null &&
        array_key_exists('country_code', $api_result) &&
        strtolower(substr($api_result['country_code'], 0, 2)) === 'tr'
    ) {
        header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
        header("Location: https://www.google.com");
        header("Connection: close");
        exit;
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
}
```

Comment: Selam, added a fix so that it works on chrome too. Should work now.

Comment: The code works, but it cannot work according to the ip country.
Turkey will work for users, will not work for other countries. Turkey must stop for those coming from the blogspot page. I tested it with a VPN but it didn't.

Comment: Then you have to use a serverside language like php. But for that you have to get a dedicated webspace

Comment: This is not a problem, I will handle it. Can you tell me what to do step by step? I'll take care of what you said.

Comment: Furkan,  I got paid membership from https://ipapi.com/ site.
How will I use this?

Comment: Hi, i added a php solution. Please mark my answer if you are happy :)